# A bunch of variables are being uninitialized. Not sure what to do

Tags: c++, function, loops, while-loop

Need help Figuring out why this error is happening, I feel like I am getting a hang of functions and arrays just a bit. This problem is supposed to read in at most 100 grades into an array and calculate the average, find the highest grade and then find the lowest grade.  I am sure you guys can tell just by looking at the code. I am just typing the rest of this so that I am able to fit the requirements needed to post the code.

-EDIT-- I wanted to reply to everyone that helped me out with this question. I fixed the problem and learned a good deal from the answers. Now all that i am having trouble with is figuring out how to appropriately pluck out the highest array and the lowest one. I should be able to figure this out, you have all been a great help and I am super grateful!

```
// This program will read in a group of test scores( positive integers from 1 to 100)
// from the keyboard and then calculates and outputs  the average score
// as well as the highest and lowest score. There will be a maximum of 100 scores.

// PLACE YOUR NAME HERE

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int GradeType[100];  // declares a new data type: 
                             // an integer array of 100 elements


float findAverage (const GradeType, int);  // finds average of all grades
int   findHighest (const GradeType, int);  // finds highest of all grades
int   findLowest  (const GradeType, int);  // finds lowest of all grades

int main()

{
    GradeType  grades;                     // the array holding the grades.
    int  numberOfGrades;                   // the number of grades read.
    int pos;                               // index to the array.

    float avgOfGrades;                     // contains the average of the grades.
    int highestGrade;                      // contains the highest grade.
    int lowestGrade;                       // contains the lowest grade.

    // Read in the values into the array

    pos = 0;
    cout << "Please input a grade from 1 to 100, (or -99 to stop)" << endl;
    cin  >> grades[pos];

    while (grades[pos] != -99)
    {
        pos++;
        cin >> grades[pos];

    }

    numberOfGrades = pos;  // Fill blank with appropriate identifier

    // call to the function to find average

    avgOfGrades = findAverage(grades, numberOfGrades);

    cout << endl << "The average of all the grades is " << avgOfGrades << endl;


    findHighest (grades, numberOfGrades);//  Fill in the call to the function that calculates highest grade


    cout << endl << "The highest grade is " << highestGrade << endl;


    findLowest (grades, numberOfGrades);// Fill in the call to the function that calculates lowest grade
   cout << "\n The lowest grade is \n" << lowestGrade<< "/n"; // Fill in code to write the lowest to the screen

    return 0;
}

//****************************************************************************
//                                 findAverage
//
// task:          This function receives an array of integers and its size.
//                It finds and returns the average of the numbers in the array
// data in:       array of floating point numbers
// data returned: avarage of the numbers in the array
//
//****************************************************************************

float findAverage (const GradeType  array, int size)

{  

    float sum = 0;   // holds the sum of all the numbers

    for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++)


       sum = sum + array[pos];

    return (sum / size);  //returns the average

}

//****************************************************************************
//                                 findHighest
//
// task:          This function receives an array of integers and its size.
//                It finds and returns the highest value of the numbers in
//                the array
// data in:       array of floating point numbers
// data returned: highest value of the numbers in the array
//
//****************************************************************************

int   findHighest (const GradeType array, int size)

{
    float highestgrade;
    for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++)
        if(array[pos]>highestgrade)
            {
                highestgrade= array[pos];
        }

        return highestgrade;
   // Fill in the code for this function

}


//****************************************************************************
//                                 findLowest
//
// task:          This function receives an array of integers and its size.
//                It finds and returns the lowest value of the numbers in 
//                the array
// data in:       array of floating point numbers
// data returned: lowest value of the numbers in the array
//
//****************************************************************************

int   findLowest  (const GradeType array, int size)

{
   float lowestgrade;
   for (int pos =0; pos > size; pos++)
       if(array[pos] < lowestgrade)
           {
               lowestgrade=array[pos];
              // Fill in the code for this function
       }
return lowestgrade;
}
```

Comment: which variables are being uninitialized

Comment: also, why dont you check for errors like someone typeing 300

Comment: also you never set grades[0] (you skip it completely)

Comment: You need to make sure pos stays less than 100.

Comment: I should do that, but the variables being uninitialized are 'highestgrade','highestGrade','lowestgrade',and 'lowestGrade'

Comment: Is this C++ or C or what?

Comment: also you test grades[pos] without ever setting it, which is allowed but the way c and c++ works, there is old memory in those cells not 0s, and potentially -99s, so it could end early

Comment: c++ has namespaces, not c

Comment: @user3063562 Why are you not collecting the return value of `findHighest` function ? I think it's return value needs to be assigned to `highestgrade`. Similarly for `findLowest` function as well.

Comment: to be honest, you do not need to store a single grade, every grade you get, see if its the highest, the lowest, and add it to a sum, in the end just divide that sum by the number of grades, then you dont need to worry about the whole array business

Comment: they change the return value, they just never initialize it which may have unexpected results (if it even compiles)

Comment: FWIW, a variable cannot “get uninitialised” any more than you can get “unborn”. You could not have been born, or you could die. Neither is called “being unborn”. Same for “uninitialised”.

Comment: something similar can be said about find lowest

Answer (score 1):

Your variable aren't being 'uninitialized' (whatever that means), they're not being initialized at all.  For example:

```
float lowestgrade;
for (int pos =0; pos > size; pos++)
    if(array[pos] < lowestgrade)     // <-- lowestgrade hasn't been initialized.

    // ...
```

Try initializing the variable in question with the first element of the array:

```
float lowestgrade = array[0];
for (int pos =0; pos > size; pos++)
    if(array[pos] < lowestgrade)     // <-- lowestgrade hasn't been initialized.

    // ...
```

You should also check that `size > 0` and performer an early exit (with a default value) or some other appropriate error handling to.

Answer (score 1):

Change these statements

```
findHighest (grades, numberOfGrades);//  Fill in the call to the function that calculates highest grade

findLowest (grades, numberOfGrades);// Fill in the call to the function that calculates lowest grade
```

to

```
highestGrade = findHighest (grades, numberOfGrades);//  Fill in the call to the function that calculates highest grade

lowestGrade = findLowest (grades, numberOfGrades);// Fill in the call to the function that calculates lowest grade
```

Also change

```
int   findLowest  (const GradeType array, int size)

{
   float lowestgrade;
   for (int pos =0; pos > size; pos++)
       if(array[pos] < lowestgrade)
           {
               lowestgrade=array[pos];
              // Fill in the code for this function
       }
return lowestgrade;
}
```

to

```
int   findLowest  (const GradeType array, int size)

{
   int lowestgrade = array[0];
   for (int pos =0; pos < size; pos++)
       if(array[pos] < lowestgrade)
           {
               lowestgrade=array[pos];
              // Fill in the code for this function
       }
return lowestgrade;
}
```

and

```
int   findHighest (const GradeType array, int size)

{
    float highestgrade;
    for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++)
        if(array[pos]>highestgrade)
            {
                highestgrade= array[pos];
        }

        return highestgrade;
   // Fill in the code for this function

}
```

to

```
int   findHighest (const GradeType array, int size)

{
    int highestgrade = array[0];
    for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++)
        if(array[pos]>highestgrade)
            {
                highestgrade= array[pos];
        }

        return highestgrade;
   // Fill in the code for this function

}
```